# Want to check in a Cisco IOS config if the VTYs have SSH only with ciscoconfparse2

Tags: python, cisco

this is my first post here!!
I´m trying to verify if an IOS config has all its VTYs with SSH only.
I'm using Python with ciscoconfparse2 library, and I created this function (at this stage I'm not using all the parameters):

Just for context, the parameters have the following info:

```
in_test = (a list with several  lines: line vty 0 4, line vty 5 15 and line vty 16 31 
in_rexp = line vty 0 4 or line vty 5 15 or line vty 16 31
in_defa = transport input ssh
```

```
def func_parent(in_parse, in_test, in_rexp, in_defa, in_neg) -\> bool:
    '''
    Checks if the VTYs have SSH only.
    '''

    object_name = [
        obj for obj in in_parse.find_parent_objects(in_rexp, in_defa)]
    print(object_name)
    if not object_name:
        print(
            Fore.RED + f'{in_test} has not SSH only ----------> 9')
        return False
    else:
        print(
            Fore.GREEN + f'{in_test} has SSH only ----------> 10')
        return True
```

So, if the list is empty, it means no ssh...
Now, for the following config...

```
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 0 0
 logging synchronous
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 exec-timeout 0 0
 logging synchronous
 length 0
transport input ssh
 line vty 16 31
 length 0
 transport input ssh
!
```

I'm receiving this...

```
\[\<IOSCfgLine # 1972 'line vty 0 4'\>\]
line vty 0 4 has SSH only ----------\> 10      \>\>\> OK

\[\<IOSCfgLine # 1977 'line vty 5 15'\>\]
line vty 5 15 has SSH only ----------\> 10     \>\>\> OK

\[\]
line vty 16 31 has not SSH only ----------\> 9  \>\>\> WRONG
```

which is wrong for the VTY 16 31.....

And for this config..

```
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 0 0
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh telnet
 length 0
line vty 5 15
 exec-timeout 0 0
 transport input telnet
 length 0
line vty 16 31
 exec-timeout 10 0
 transport input ssh telnet
 length 0
!
```

... this results...

```
\[\<IOSCfgLine # 14395 'line vty 0 4'\>\]
line vty 0 4 has SSH only ----------\> 10         \>\>\> WRONG

\[\]
line vty 5 15 has not SSH only ----------\> 9     \>\>\> OK

\[\]
line vty 16 31 has not SSH only ----------\> 9     \>\>\> OK
```

I'm guessing that the match condition is not working with the combo ssh and telnet.

I tryed with find_parent_objects and also with find_child_objects with the same result.
Maybe this is not the best way to check the SSH only in the config, appreciate your help!

TIA

Comment: I think I found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.
The running config has an space at the beginning of the child lines, so the regexp I have to use, should take this into account.
Since I was following the examples in the ciscoparseconf2 documentation, they do not include the spaces at the begining in the queryes for the functions find_parent_objects and find_child_objetcts. As soon as I reformulated the regexp like this ^\s+transport\s+input\s+ssh$, it started to return what I was expecting.